# Are the latest iPod Nanos running iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipod

The current version of the iPod Nano looks a lot like it is running the iOS. Is it actually running a scaled-down version of the software on the iPhones, or is it just a themed version of the classic iPod software?

Comment: Does not, and has not. Though the familiarity is quite remarkable for a completely different OS, no?

Comment: That it is. I was trying to figure out if there was any chance of Apple ever letting developers port apps over to the device. Checking my email on a watch would be awesome.

Comment: No it wouldn't. Reading song information is not bad. Reading an e-mail of any length is absurdly bad on a screen that small.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [this article](http://www.cultofmac.com/57467/apple-touchscreen-ipod-nano-does-not-run-ios/), an Apple spokesman stated that the touch-screen iPod Nano does not run iOS.